# Iterate over all variables in a function in a decorator without knowing the names of the variables used

Tags: python, python-decorators

This is a very dumbed down version of my actual use case: I want to write a decorator that checks the defined variables in a function and if they have a special type, a certain action is done.

E.g.: Check over all variables that are defined in a function and see if there is a single float value used. I know about `locals()`, `globals()`, and `dir()`. However with none of those I was able to achieve this.

Here is a code of that uses dir() to mimick the behaviour but has no access to the variables of `func2`

```
def func1(f):
    """decorator for checking if a float variable was used in a func"""
    
    for attr in dir(f):
        
        v =  getattr(f, attr)
        
        if type(v) == float:
            print("FLOAT WAS USED!")
    return f

@func1
def func2():
    THE_INTEGER_VARIABLE = 10
    THE_FLOAT_VARIABLE = 0.5

func2()
```

Comment: At the time `func1` is called, `func2` is just the function object.  Only during execution will the variables exist in its `__dict__`.  You can access the names of variables used in the function's code with `f.__code__.co_varnames`, but that is only a tuple of local variable names: `('THE_INTEGER_VARIABLE', 'THE_FLOAT_VARIABLE')`

Comment: @MarkTolonen I tried `print(func2.__dict__)` at the end inside `func2`, it was empty...

Comment: @KellyBundy Sorry, use `print(vars())` or `print(locals())` or `print(dir())`.  Was thinking of a class and `self.__dict__`.